# Special filename in OS X; semantics of asterisk?

Tags: mac-osx, asterisk

So I'm using Mac OS X 10.5, and I have a file called

```
_Mail.grxml
```

that is being handled funny.

```
ls -l
```

will show the file, but

```
ls -l *
```

will not. It's just this one file; note

```
ls -l | wc -l
```

gives 43 (the number of files in the directory), but

```
ls -l * | wc -l
```

gives 42.

So the question is -- Are there filenames that OSX just doesn't play nicely with? Or are the semantics of the * on the command line different from what I expect?

(Note this is NOT the only file whose name begins with an underscore; the other files are picked up just fine by *).

Comment: what is the output of ls -lab

Comment: Check to see what the troublesome file is *really* called - either pipe the output of ls -l into 'less' (it shows non-printable characters quite clearly), or into 'od -c' or similar.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what shell you're using, but if it's Bash (or similar) you may have the environment variable `GLOBIGNORE` set to exclude some patterns when you do pathname expansion such as in `ls -l *`.

```
GLOBIGNORE
              A colon-separated list of patterns defining the set of filenames
              to be ignored by pathname expansion.  If a filename matched by a
              pathname  expansion  pattern also matches one of the patterns in
              GLOBIGNORE, it is removed from the list of matches.
```

```
$ touch _Mail.grxml
$ ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 2009-11-13 14:57 _Mail.grxml
$ ls -l *
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 2009-11-13 14:57 _Mail.grxml
$ GLOBIGNORE=*.grxml
$ ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 2009-11-13 14:57 _Mail.grxml
$ ls -l *
ls: cannot access _*: No such file or directory
```

(That's the only file in the test directory.)

Answer (score 0):

A thought - is it starting with ._ (dot underscore, not just underscore)?

Comment: Nope; starts with an underscore (no dot).